# is it possible to add two datasourse attribute in a single antd table?

Tags: reactjs

In this code, I have two selectors value. I want to use it in single table. how can i use it?

```
const FilingsTable = () =>{
  const selectorValue=useRecoilValue(filingsSelector);
  const financalyearSelectorValue=useRecoilValue(financialyearSelector);
  
  return(
    <div>
    <Table  columns={FilingsColumns} dataSource={financalyearSelectorValue}  />
    </div>
   )
}
export default FilingsTable;
```

Comment: You should add Recoil to your tags. I don't even know where the `Table` component comes from, could you clarify that?

Answer (score 1):

You can merge data and pass it as a data source to table.
Note: I suppose the data type is of array and both data sources have same keys

```
const FilingsTable = () =>{
const selectorValue=useRecoilValue(filingsSelector);
const financalyearSelectorValue=useRecoilValue(financialyearSelector);
const data = [...selectorValue, ...financalyearSelectorValue]

return(
  <div>
  <Table  columns={FilingsColumns} dataSource={data}  />
</div>
)
}

export default FilingsTable;
```

Comment: I think you forgot to pass `Data` to the Table.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for correction